# How do I lock my computer and keep the screen black?

Tags: display, intel-graphics, hdmi, lock-screen, 21.10

I use my Ubuntu machine as a media computer, sometimes I lock it and walk away which normally blacks the screen and then after a few seconds stops sending signal to the monitor/TV. When the screen is fully black, my TV turns off the backlights and is for my purposes off. However, when there is no signal, I instead get the TV's "no signal" prompt, which turns on the backlight.

I want to lock my screen with Ctrl-L and have the screen go black, but *never actually stop sending the black screen signal* to the TV/monitor, so that appears off but isn't actually. I want to prevent the TV from showing the "no signal"  prompt by having Ubuntu continue to send a black screen to the TV when its locked.

I don't want to use DPMS to turn the monitor on/off on demand as my TV isn't reliable at turning back on. I'm using Intel graphics on an i5-2500k running Ubuntu 21.10 with the TV running over HDMI.

Comment: There's a fundamental misunderstanding in the way you wrote this question: There is no "black screen signal" being sent, ever. There's a fraction of a second, at most, when the desktop has been turned off but the video output not turned off (capacitors an all) that is *interpreted* by the TV as signal. In a nutshell what you want can't be done because it simply doesn't exist.

Comment: Maybe it would be easier if I framed the question as something like "how do I make the lockscreen just show black until I move the mouse". All I want to do is send a screen full of black pixels instead of turning off the output, that's what I mean by black screen signal.